# --disable-gpu-vsync does not work in chromium with NVIDIA GTX 960?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I am using `NVIDIA GTX 960` gpu in my pc with `windows 10` as the operation system. I have been trying to measure the actual fps value in one of my `Three.js` application. So i decided to run `Chromium` with flag `--disable-gpu-vsync`. Unfortunately it didnt work. The fps is still capped at 60. I have tried to disable `vsync` from the graphics driver without any success.

On the other hand, `--disable-gpu-vsync` worked at my worked pc with `NVIDIA GTX 750` and `Windows 7`.

My question is, why isn't it working? Am i missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search, i have found that `Windows 10` forces the `v-sync` on even if it is disabled.

Comment: Can you provide any links please?